A partial order on conjugacy classes
My esteemed colleague Nathan Bowler has drawn my attention to the
following partial order. Let $G$ be a group of permutations of an
infinite set $X$.  If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are elements of $G$ we say
that an injection $\pi:X \to X$ is an embedding of $\sigma$ into
$\tau$ if $\pi\sigma = \tau\pi$. Let us write $\sigma \leq \tau$ if there is an embedding of $\sigma$ into $\tau$; then $\leq$ is a preorder on $G$. There is a Cantor–Bernstein-like theorem for $\leq$ that says that if $\sigma \leq \tau \leq \sigma$ then $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are conjugate (at least if $G$ contains all permutations of $X$) or at any rate have the same cycle type.
Has this preorder (or partial order on conjugacy classes) manifested itself in the literature anywhere?

What does $\pi\sigma$ mean?

@bof this must mean composition (of maps $X \to X$).

@SamHopkins I understood that it means composition of maps. Both $\pi\sigma$ and $\sigma\pi$ are compositions of the maps $\pi$ and $\sigma$. I meant to ask which one is $\pi\sigma$. Because some people write $\pi\sigma$ when they mean $\sigma\pi$ and for all I know the OP is one of them.

@bof ah, I see. Well changing from one convention to the other would just amount to replacing $\leq$ with $\geq$, which shouldn't matter for the question.
